# Do we need article “the” with "Wonder Woman" and other superheroes?

Tags: definite-article

> - She wants to be like Wonder Woman when she grows up.

Can we use article “the” in this sentence, if not, then why?

Comment: **Wonder Woman** is a proper noun. Some proper nouns *(**The** Hebrides, **The** Taj Mahal, **The** Himalayas,...)* have the definite article ***included*** in their name. But Wonder Woman doesn't, as could easily be established from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman) (and many dictionaries).

Comment: In the early days of _Batman_, he was referred to as _the Bat-man_, i.e. it was not seen as a name; but it soon started being treated as a name.

Comment: @ColinFine The same goes for “The Hulk”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is 'the' added before Wasp but not before Antman?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/171462/why-is-the-added-before-wasp-but-not-before-antman)

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the title of a superhero is used like a proper name and generally does not take an article.

However, you will sometimes see an article used with a superhero (or other fictional character) if the writer is trying to single out one particular version of that character as opposed to all of the other versions of the character depicted throughout years of representation in comics, cartoons, movies, etc.

For example:

> **The** Wonder Woman we saw in last year's movie was very different from **the** Wonder Woman I remember from watching Saturday morning TV.